# controller/create/id not allowing any data - Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm designing a system where I need to create a comment that leaves a comment on a specific user's page.

Currently in my `employercommentscontroller` I have the create function

```
public function create($id)
{
    $user = User::where('employee_id', $id)->get();
    return view('comments.create', compact('user'));
}
```

Here is the route to this controller file

```
Route::resource('/reviews', 'EmployerCommentsController');
```

This is so that I can display information about the user that the comment is being left about. When I go to the url.
When I visit `/reviews/create/2`, I get a `notfoundhttpexception`. What do I need to change to be able to pass just the ID to my create method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
Route::get('/reviews/create/{id}', 'EmployerCommentsController@create');
```

For further information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Comment: Thanks , I was avoiding put extraneous routes in but it looks like this may be the only solution. Cheers for the speedy response!

Comment: @LiamS Cheers! If you like it, then you can choose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create additional routes and you want to use standard RESTful controller, you can just create link with GET parameter:

```
<a href="/reviews/create?id=2">Write a comment</a>
```

And then get this parameter in controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $id = request()->input('id');
```